# Where ADOP Gerrit projects repositories are saved?

Tags: docker, gerrit

Where ADOP Gerrit saves all projects on HOST and is it write to delete them from host?

maybe they are in var folder but seams not:

```
[host]$ ls var

account  db     games     lib    lock  mail  opt       repos_new  spool  yp
```

Comment: Gerrit doesn't save projects on LDAP... I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira thank for your useless coment

Comment: I was just trying to understand your problem. How could I answer your question without understand it? Your comment was really rude... totally unnecessary. Now that you have fixed your question (changing LDAP to HOST) I was able to answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know where Gerrit saves the Git repositories (Gerrit projects) search for the **basePath** definition at the **$GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config** configuration file, like in following example:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
```

Normally this path is defined relative to $GERRIT-SITE but it can be defined absolutely too.

To learn more about this see [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#gerrit.basePath).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it by my self the project repositories are saved in /data/git/repos/